# Black and white linen with espresso furniture

Tags: black, white

What would be a good accent color for espresso furniture with black and white damask design on linen?

Comment: Hi there! I'm not sure how on-topic this is for graphic design, but in any case it looks quite broad. To be able to answer we generally need samples and explanations on things you have tried and why they didn't work.

Comment: Yup, photo would be a big help!

Comment: Any color will work excellent with black white and deep brown.

Comment: As all design does it depends entirely on context. Not only what the furniture is but the rest of the room and lighting. If its a well lit room overlooking the beach for example then I might use a blue or yellow. If its a room in a mountain resort though I'd go with a rich gold or magenta. As Scott said any color can work but also as Yisela said photos and samples help.

Answer (score -1):

I would use colors from this palette 
[image]
combined with (possibly high-key) grayscale. No other colors